# Rewrite a specific path in xginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite a specific path using nginx. I have setup my server using nginx/php-fpm/php and it is working fine.

I have the following server configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain.com;
    root /srv/www/domain.com/public;

    location ~ ^/index.php($|/) {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(.*)$;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location / {
       index index.php;
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
    }
}
```

And this works. I.e. when I go to `http://domain.com` it renders the php file just fine. However I am now trying to rewrite a specific path `/update/whatever` to `/update.php?var=whatever`. In order to do this I have added the following `location` block to my config (before the `location ~ ^/index.php($|/) {` block):

```
location ~* ^\/update/(\w+)$ {
    rewrite ^/update/(\w+)$ /update.php?browser=$1 last;
}
```

But when I try to access the URL `http://domain.com/update/whatever` it downloads the php file instead of serving the parsed output from PHP.

I have also tried adding the `fastcgi` directives to that location block with the same result. Anybody can tell me what I have messed up in my config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
location ~ ^/index.php($|/) {
```

tells nginx to pass only `index.php` to php interpreter and you need it to also apply to other php files so more generic rule is required here:

```
location ~ ^/(.*).php($|/) {
```